# Selecting polygons not touching other polygons in same feature class using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a feature class with a bunch of polygons depicting buildings in it and I'm trying to select all the ones that are by themselves, that means any building that is by itself. There are also buildings that are adjacent to other buildings but I'm not interested in those.

Does anyone have any idea how to accomplish this in ArcMap?

Edit: Here's an example image for context. The red circles would be ones I wouldn't want to select and the green ones are ones I would like to select. The polygons are oddly shaped for fencing, but I just refer to them as buildings.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you provide screenshots of your polygons to better assist you with your question?